# PostgreSQL string escaping settings

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 servers: `S1`, `S2` with the same `SELECT version()` with the same databases `test` containing a table `t1` that has column of type `text[]`.

I try to insert array of 2 strings with symbol `"` in one of them:

```
INSERT into t1 (columnname) VALUES (`{"str1", "str2\"with quote symbol"}`)
```

`S1` works good, but `S2` throws an error:

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{"str1", "str2"with quote symbol"}"
```

Lets add one more `\` to the request:

```
INSERT into t1 (columnname) VALUES (`{"str1", "str2\\"with quote symbol"}`)
```

Now `S2` works, but `S1` says:

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{"str1", "str2\\"with quote symbol"}"
```

Is there some escaping settings somewhere in postgres?

The servers is accessed via 2 independent pgbouncer instances, but i think that is not related to question.

Comment: Don't use backticks; they mean nothing.

Answer (score 8):

Escaping a single quote in (standard) SQL is done by using two single quotes, e.g.
 `'Peter''s house'`

I prefer using the explicit `ARRAY[..]` which also needs one less quote, so your insert could be written as:

```
INSERT into t1 (columnname) 
VALUES (ARRAY['str1', 'str2''with quote symbol']);
```

In versions before 9.1 Postgres allowed to use `\` as an alternate escaping character but would log a warning if being used. Since 9.1 the config parameter `standard_conforming_strings` is enabled and thus the `\` can't be used as an escape a single quote.

Answer (score 5):

- double quotes are used to quote identifiers
- single quotes are used for string literals
- backticks have no meaning (except in the psql frontend)
- the `VALUES` statement is followed by a comma **list** of parenthesized expression lists, each expressionlist constitutes one literal *row*.
- `E'string\'with a single quote'` can be used to force C-style backslash escaping. It is a Postgres extension. (the existing SQL way to escape characters inside strings is barely usable)
- arrays are also a (debatable) Postgres extension. The *outer* quotes in the value list are still single quotes; if quotes are needed *inside* the `'{ ... , ... }'` these need to be double quotes, and backslash-escaping is enabled. (this is Ok, since the *inside*  already is an extension, so no existing syntax is offended)

---

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (columnname varchar);
INSERT into t1 (columnname) VALUES ('str1') ,( E'str2\'with quote symbol');

CREATE TABLE t2 ("Columnname" varchar[] );
INSERT into t2 ("Columnname") VALUES ( '{ "str1" , "str2\"with a double quote" }' );

SELECT * FROM t1;
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

Comment: What about array of strings? I cannot write `'{'a', 'b'}'` because second `'` will conflict with first `'`

Comment: Note that the \ escape character is deprecated and disabled by default since 9.1. The behaviour depends on the value of the configuration parameter `standard_conforming_strings`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS